# System.DllNotFoundException: can't load sfml.graphics

Tags: c#, dependencies, sfml

I've downloaded sfml from NuGet to develop with it in C#. I'm using the 2019 community version for C# and version 2.5 for sfml. With the code:

```
using SFML.Graphics;
using SFML.Window;

namespace sfml_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(200, 200), "test");
            CircleShape cs = new CircleShape(100.0f);
            cs.FillColor = Color.Green;
            window.SetActive();
            while (window.IsOpen)
            {
                window.Clear();
                window.DispatchEvents();
                window.Draw(cs);
                window.Display();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:
`System.DllNotFoundException: 'Can't load DLL csfml-graphics: Can't find given module. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'`

I know that there already are some answers to similar questions, but these questions have been answered in 2010, with programs that don't seem to support Windows 10 (like [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/), I also did not understand the explanations.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

P.S. I'm trying to make a 2D ray tracer in C# and need a window to display it on. Most of the windows I can find are used for UI (Windows.Forms, GTK#) or are meant to work for 3D (OpenTK). Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Most likely, the SFML libraries aren't being copied to output directory. You should see the DLLs in solution explorer, likely in the root of your project; ensure that `Copy to output directory` is set to `True`

Comment: Btw, SFML is great for C++ 2D game development; for C#, I strongly recommend looking into MonoGame instead.

Comment: I just want a simple window on which I can do pixel manipulation for a raytracer, I suppose MonoGame would work. @CoolBots

Answer (score 1):

The CSFML NuGet package seems to be the issue.

When you added SFML.Net as a referenced package, the CSFML one is also downloaded but not actually referenced to the project. During compilation, no dll gets copied to the OutputDir.

A "solution" to this, is to copy the libraries from the package to your output directory. You can copy the following 5 lines into the post-build event of your project to do that, but don't forget to select *Execute post-buid event : Always*

```
xcopy /C /E /R /I /K /Y "$(SolutionDir)packages\CSFML.2.5.0\runtimes\win-$(Platform)\native\csfml-Audio.dll" "$(TargetDir)csfml-Audio.dll*"
xcopy /C /E /R /I /K /Y "$(SolutionDir)packages\CSFML.2.5.0\runtimes\win-$(Platform)\native\csfml-Graphics.dll" "$(TargetDir)csfml-Graphics.dll*"
xcopy /C /E /R /I /K /Y "$(SolutionDir)packages\CSFML.2.5.0\runtimes\win-$(Platform)\native\csfml-System.dll" "$(TargetDir)csfml-System.dll*"
xcopy /C /E /R /I /K /Y "$(SolutionDir)packages\CSFML.2.5.0\runtimes\win-$(Platform)\native\csfml-Window.dll" "$(TargetDir)csfml-Window.dll*"
xcopy /C /E /R /I /K /Y "$(SolutionDir)packages\CSFML.2.5.0\runtimes\win-$(Platform)\native\openal32.dll" "$(TargetDir)openal32.dll*"
```